# Is there something wrong with these rewrite rules?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

For my website, I have the following apache config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

    #.........

    DocumentRoot /var/www/web

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/web/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    #.........

    <Directory "/var/www/web/">
      RewriteEngine On
      # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
      # getting no_script_name to work
      RewriteBase /

      # redirect www if necessary
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

      # we skip all files with .something
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
      # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
      RewriteRule .* - [L]

      #root url
      RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

      # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically, any request on a nonexistent file without dot is redirected to the my front web controller. It seems to work well but I don't understand why I have many of the following lines in the log file:

```
[Mon Aug 06 12:29:52 2012] [error] [client 188.165.238.151] File does not exist: /var/www/web/webcalendar
[Mon Aug 06 12:29:52 2012] [error] [client 188.165.238.151] File does not exist: /var/www/web/calendar
[Mon Aug 06 12:29:52 2012] [error] [client 188.165.238.151] File does not exist: /var/www/web/webcal
[Mon Aug 06 12:29:52 2012] [error] [client 188.165.238.151] File does not exist: /var/www/web/cal
[Mon Aug 06 12:29:52 2012] [error] [client 188.165.238.151] File does not exist: /var/www/web/install
```

If I try URLs like `http://domain.com/cal` or `http://www.domain.com/cal`, my log shows the error returned by my application, not by Apache:

```
[Wed Aug 08 09:06:04 2012] [error] [client 82.60.63.56] Action "cal/index" does not exist.
```

How is it possible that apache returns the error directly without sending the request to my application?

**EDIT**:

This is the output of `apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain-ssl:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain:1)
         port 80 namevhost mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain:1)
Syntax OK
```

**UPDATE**:

Here is the log of a request:

```
211.154.213.122 - - [15/Aug/2012:12:39:45 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#7f87db86bf40][rid#7f87db6990a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/web/] add path info postfix: /var/www/web/phpMyAdmin -> /var/www/web/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php
211.154.213.122 - - [15/Aug/2012:12:39:45 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#7f87db86bf40][rid#7f87db6990a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/web/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php -> phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php
211.154.213.122 - - [15/Aug/2012:12:39:45 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#7f87db86bf40][rid#7f87db6990a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/web/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php'
211.154.213.122 - - [15/Aug/2012:12:39:45 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#7f87db86bf40][rid#7f87db6990a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/web/] add path info postfix: /var/www/web/phpMyAdmin -> /var/www/web/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php
211.154.213.122 - - [15/Aug/2012:12:39:45 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#7f87db86bf40][rid#7f87db6990a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/web/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php -> phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php
211.154.213.122 - - [15/Aug/2012:12:39:45 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#7f87db86bf40][rid#7f87db6990a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/web/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php'
211.154.213.122 - - [15/Aug/2012:12:39:45 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#7f87db86bf40][rid#7f87db6990a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/web/] pass through /var/www/web/phpMyAdmin
```

Which produces the following error:

```
[Wed Aug 15 12:39:45 2012] [error] [client 211.154.213.122] File does not exist: /var/www/stmtc/web/phpMyAdmin
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$` matches a file with a "." *anywhere* in the filename (because you haven't anchored the beginning of the expression to anything).  So not just `.something` but also `something.png` and so forth.  Maybe you want `/\..+$`, which would match antyhing with a "." following a "/".

Comment: What do you see when you turn on verbose logging of rewrite processing?  This should show you exactly what's happening.

Comment: @larsks thank you for your suggestion, I have enabled rewrite login and will update my question with the result.

Comment: @larsks please see the update in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @larsks suggestion and reading the rewrite logs I understand that the error logged:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/web/phpMyAdmin
```

was not for the exact request `http://domain.com/phpMyAdmin` but for the request `http://domain.com/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php`. The rewrite rule was not called because of the dot in the file name. So all is normal and work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know for sure without seeing your entire config, but on the surface this looks like a variation of the "trailing slash problem". I suspect that with a little analysis and experimentation you may validate this.

In the event it is useful, what is going on with Apache is that a request without a trailing slash or file extension is ambiguous - Apache doesn't know whether the request is for a file resource or for a directory resource. It sees the request, parses it, and looks for the resource on the file system assuming it is a file. If the file isn't there, it'll issue a redirect by adding a trailing slash, on the assumption that it should try the request again, but as directory level request since the file didn't exist.

I realize that this doesn't map totally to your problem description but your rewrites are possibly intervening here and making this process a bit less intuitive than normal.

@larsks suggestion of turning on verbose rewrite logging is a very good one, and should shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: thank you @mcauth I have enabled rewrite login and I will update my question with the result.

Comment: please see the update in my question